# Is there a way to show both labels "p.format" and "p.signif" in one bracket with stat_compare_mean?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

While creating my plots for my paper, i wanted to show both the exact p-values in the plot and add the asterisks to the appropriate brackets next to the p-values. I used stat_compare_mean for this but cant figure out how i can use both at the same time.
So is there a way to add both the asterisks and the pvalues onto one bracket using stat_compare_mean?

I tried to use the normal stat_compare_mean and added both the label=p.format and label=p.signif but this didnt work (not to my suprise). Im still new to R and just learned the basics so ye....

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried with reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `paste` them together with a newline character:

```r
library(ggpubr)

ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
          color = "dose", palette = "npg") +
  stat_compare_means(aes(label = paste0('p = ', after_stat(p.format), '\n',
                                        after_stat(p.signif))), label.y = 40, 
                     vjust = 1, method = "t.test", ref.group = "0.5")
```

[image]